# React doesn't route when writing manually .htaccess

Tags: javascript, reactjs, .htaccess, react-router

I'm trying to set `.htaccess` file to route `React` pages. Here is my Router:

```
<Route path = "/" component = {App}>
    <Header propContext={{useUserContext, setUserContext}}/>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Index} />

    <Route path="/index" component={Index} />
    <Route path="/xxx/:id" component={Xxx} />
    <Route path="/somepath" component={Somepath} />
    <Route path="/anotherpath" component={Anotherpath} />
    <Route path="/yyy/:id" component={Yyy} />
    
    <Footer />
</Route>
```

And here is my `htaccess` file on the server:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

When I write manually the URL the `https://example.com/index` , `https://example.com/somepath`, `https://example.com/anotherpath` URLs work fine. But `https://example.com/xxx/14` or `https://example.com/yyy/53` URLs don't work, show blank page and throws these error on the console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '>'
Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.
```

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36623117/284199) answer, but at [here](https://www.edureka.co/community/67651/error-react-router-urls-work-when-refreshing-writing-manually?ranMID=42536&ranEAID=a1LgFw09t88&ranSiteID=a1LgFw09t88-AqXixUK.cjvzwwvW4I13ow&LSNSUBSITE=Omitted_a1LgFw09t88) someone suggested htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this with [HashRouter](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/HashRouter) like that:

```
<HashRouter>
<Route path = "/" component = {App}>
    <Header propContext={{useUserContext, setUserContext}}/>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Index} />

    <Route path="/index" component={Index} />
    <Route path="/xxx/:id" component={Xxx} />
    <Route path="/somepath" component={Somepath} />
    <Route path="/anotherpath" component={Anotherpath} />
    <Route path="/yyy/:id" component={Yyy} />
    
    <Footer />
</Route>
</HashRouter>
```